# How to Best Alias an IN condition?

Tags: sql

I am trying to alias an IN condition to group states by region.  What would be the best way to write this in SQL, as I am not able to alias on a WHERE clause?

```
select state_cd from table
where state_cd in (‘PA’,’NY’,’NJ’,’CT’,’RI’,’MA’,’VT’,’NH’,’ME’) Northeast;
```

Comment: You can't do this, you can use comments, if you want.

Comment: you can alias `state_cd` in `SELECT` with `Northeast`.

Comment: An alias is used in further references to an item. How would you want to use it in this situation?

Comment: If you want to designate these states as being in the north east, why not add the column to your table? Perhaps call it `region`. Then your query becomes `select state_cd from table where region = 'Northeast';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the alias on the column `select state_cd as Northeast` if you need to, but it can't be done on the `IN` clause.

Alternatively, use a `CASE` statement if you are likely to have several different variations on the `state_cd` field.

Comment: can i use an in condition in a case statement?

Comment: @BarryMahnly Yes - `SELECT CASE WHEN state_cd in (‘PA’,’NY’,’NJ’,’CT’,’RI’,’MA’,’VT’,’NH’,’ME’) THEN 'Northeast' ELSE 'Other' END FROM table`

Comment: the following worked for me:

SELECT
 case
 when when state_cd in ('NH','ME','VT','MA','RI','CT','NY','NJ','PA') then 'Northeast'
  when state_cd in ('OK','AR','TX','LA','KY','TN','MS','AL','WV','DE','MD','VA','DC','NC','SC','GA','FL') then 'South'
  when state_cd in ('ND','SD','NE','KS','MN','IA','MO','WI','IL','MI','IN','OH') then 'Midwest'
  when state_cd in ('WA','OR','CA','ID','NV','MT','WY','CO','UT','AZ','NM','AK','HI') then 'West'
 end Region
from 
FROM table;

Answer (score 0):

One possibility if you just need it for readabilty create a table/view/cte of that name and join with it.

```
with Northeast as (Select 'PA' as state_cd union Select 'NY' union Select 'NY' union Select 'NJ' union Select 'CT' union Select 'RI' union Select 'MA' union Select 'VT' union Select 'NH' union Select 'ME')

select * 
  from table
         join Northeast on table.state_cd = Northeast.state_cd
```

Comment: For you. Presumably not. For me. Rather not. For him? Maybe. Just take the select and ignore the cte part and lets think its a view. Then it might be more readable to some people.